# chrome 拡張で音声を再生したい

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "test",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "https://*/*" ],
      "js": ["test.js"],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "*.mp3"
  ]
}
```

test.js

```
 const audioElem = new Audio();
 audioElem.src = chrome.extension.getURL("sound.mp3");
 audioElem.play();
```

という 2 つのファイルと sound.mp3 をフォルダに入れて
ページを開くと音を鳴らす最小セットの拡張機能を chrome にインストールしたんですが

```
test.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first. https://goo.gl/xX8pDD
```

というエラーが出ます

これまでも同様のコードで特定のサイトの特定のDOMをみはって
出現すると音を鳴らすという拡張を作っていて現在もその拡張は動いてます

再インストールして動かなくなると困るので試せないんですが
最後に作ったのは半年ほど前なので
ここ最近の仕様変更で何か変わったんでしょうか

それともこのコードに何か見落としがあったりするんでしょうか

---

https://qiita.com/A-Kouki/items/40020f7ef30a4e3b6d79
こういう対処法もあるみたいなんですが
既存のコードはこういうのをした覚えはなくうごいています

自分用で人に配布したりするものではないのでポリシーを変更してしまってもいいんですが
このサイトに書いてある
chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy
にアクセスしてみても
「Autoplay policy」
「No user gesture is required」
という項目が見当たりません

Comment: エラーで表示されたメッセージ中の https://goo.gl/xX8pDD に経緯や対応方法が書かれているように見えますが、こちらは確認しましたか？

Comment: 確認しましたが拡張機能でタグから音声ファイルを読んでるわけではないのでできる対処は chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy をいじることだと思うんですがその設定画面いそれらしい項目が見当たらずに困っています。あとこれまで同様のプログラムでそういう設定をしたことがなかったのになぜ今回音声が鳴らなくなったのか条件が知りたかったのもあります

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://goo.gl/xX8pDD
を参考にオプションをつけてChrome起動すれば音を出せました。

chrome.exe --disable-features=AutoplayIgnoreWebAudio